# Deriving the probability of winning a dice game with two different sets of dice?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expected-value, dice

Purely out of curiosity, I wanted to determine the probability of winning a dice game when each set of dice is not the same. For example, Player 1 has a dice set of $[d_{20}, d_{4}]$, and Player 2 has $[d_6, d_6, d_6, d_6]$. I can get the average outcome of both sets (13 and 14, respectively), but I can't seem to figure out a way to get the exact probability of one player winning.

When I simulate this scenario in a program, the average win rate is approximately 52.5% in favor of Player 2. I was wondering if there is a way to figure out the average win rate for this scenario and if I could generalize this for any two sets of dice.

Comment: Can you please clarify if the dice are standard $6$-sided dice? What are $d_{20}, d_4, d_6$?

Comment: A bit tedious, but you can simply compute the probability of getting each possible score for each player.  Then you can read off the probability you want.

Comment: How many throws in the game ?

Comment: @lulu Since you understood the game, can you please answer my question? Thank you.

Comment: @tommyinnit09   Sure.  $d_n$ means a fair $n-$ sided die, with faces $\{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$.  Standard die is $d_6$. Thus, in this case, player $\#2$ just has four ordinary fair dice.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation) is a reference.

Comment: @lulu Ok, so each player has more than one dice, like P1 has $d_{20}$ and $d_6$. Thanks.

Comment: @tommyinnit09  You got it.  Except that Player $\#1$ has $d_{20}$ and $d_4$ in this case.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130025/formula-for-dropping-dice-non-brute-force), which covers dropping the lowest dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a player throws $\ d\ $ dice, then his score $\ S\ $ is the sum of $\ d\ $ independent random variables:
$$
S=\sum_{i=1}^dT_i\ ,
$$
where $\ T_i\ $ is the number appearing on the uppermost face of the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ die.  If player $1$'s score is $\ S_1\ $, player $2$'s is $\ S_2\ $, and the difference $\ Z=$$\,S_2-S_1\ $ has probability mass function $\ \zeta:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow[0,1]\ $ then the probability that player $2$ wins is just
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Z>0)&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(Z=i)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\zeta(i)\ .
\end{align}
Although the above sums have an upper limit of $\ \infty\ $, in fact they're only finite, because $\ \zeta\ $ has only a finite number of non-zero values.

Now the probability mass function $\ \sigma\ $ of the sum $\ X_1+X_2\ $ of two independent random variables $\ X_1,X_2\ $, with probability mass functions $\ \chi_1, \chi_2\ $ respectively, is just the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) of  $\ \chi_1\ $ and $\ \chi_2\ $:
\begin{align}
\sigma(j)&=\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2=j)\\
&=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty\mathbb{P}(X_1=i,X_2=j-i)\\
&=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty\mathbb{P}(X_1=i)\,\mathbb{P}(X_2=j-i)\\
&=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty\chi_1(i)\,\chi_2(j-i)\\
&=(\chi_1*\chi_2)(j)\ .
\end{align}
The operation of convolution is associative and commutative, so the individual convolution operations in a series of convolutions $\ \chi_1*$$\,\chi_2*$$\,\dots*$$\,\chi_d\ $ can be carried out in any order.

Thus, the probability mass functions of $\ S_1\ $ and $\ S_2\ $ are just the convolutions of the probability mass functions of the summands of which they are the sum.  When an $\ n$-faced fair die labelled with the numbers $\ 1,2,\dots,n\ $ is thrown, the probability mass function $\ \mu_n\ $ of the number appearing on its uppermost face  is given by
$$
\mu_n(i)=\cases{\frac{1}{n}&if $\ 1\le i\le n$\\
0&if $\ i\le0\text{ or }\ n+1\le i\ $.}
$$
If player $1$ throws $\ d_1\ $ dice with $\ n_1,n_2,\dots,n_{d_1}\ $ faces and player $2$ throws $\ d_2\ $ dice with $\ m_1,m_2,\dots,m_{d_2}\ $ faces, then the probability mass functions of $\ S_1\ $ and $\ S_2\ $ will be
\begin{align}
\sigma_1&=\mu_{n_1}*\mu_{n_2}*\dots*\mu_{n_{d_1}}\ \text{ and}\\
\sigma_2&=\mu_{m_1}*\mu_{m_2}*\dots*\mu_{m_{d_2}}
\end{align}
respectively. The probability mass function $\ \zeta\ $ of $\ Z=S_2-S_1\ $ will be given by
$$
\zeta=\sigma_2*\sigma_1^-\ .\,
$$
where $\ \sigma_1^-(i)=\sigma_1(-i)\ $ for all $\ i\in\mathbb{Z}\ $. For the specific problem posed in the question we'll have $\ \sigma_1=\mu_{20}*\mu_4\ $ and $\ \sigma_2=\mu_6*\mu_6*\mu_6*\mu_6\ $.

Thus, in principle there's nothing really very complicated in calculating the probability of each of the player's winning the game or the probability of a tie. The messiness mentioned in [user2661923's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598862/deriving-the-probability-of-winning-a-dice-game-with-two-different-sets-of-dice/4598889#4598889) is really just that of calculating the necessary convolutions by hand. It's not difficult to write a computer program or script to do the job.

The [R statistical package](https://www.r-project.org/) incorporates several procedures for computing convolutions.  Unfortunately, none that I found seems capable of directly calculating the convolution of two probability mass functions that assign positive probabilities to negative integers. With a little bit of fiddling, it would be possible to adapt [gconv](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/SensitivityCaseControl/html/gconv.html) to do this, but since I'm not all that familiar with the R scripting language, I guessed I would probably find it easier to write a   [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) script to do all the calculations. The script below calculates the probabilities of each of the two player's winning the game described in the question. If you copy and paste it into the [online Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) and press submit, it produces the following output:

```
    probability player 2 wins = 9071/17280 , = approximately 0.5249421296
    probability of tie = 2581/51840 = approximately 0.04978780864
    probability player 1 wins = 11023/25920 = approximately 0.4252700617
```

in good agreement with the result you obtained by simulation.

You can play around with what happens when the players are given different sets of dice by modifying the values of the variables `p1dice` and `p2dice` in the first two lines.

```
   p1dice:=[20,4];
   p2dice:=[6,6,6,6];

   setupdie:=function(n)
      dn:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,2+n);
      dn[1,1]:=1;
      dn[1,2]:=n;
      for i in [1..n] do
         dn[1,i+2]:=1/n;
      end for;
      return dn;
    end function;

    convolve:= function(a,b)
       minv:=a[1,1]+b[1,1];
       maxv:=a[1,2]+b[1,2];
       n:=Integers()!(maxv+1-minv);
       result:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,2+n);
       result[1,1]:=minv;
       result[1,2]:=maxv;
       for i in [1..(a[1,2]+1-a[1,1])] do
           for j in [1..(b[1,2]+1-b[1,1])] do
              result[1,i+j+1]:=result[1,i+j+1]+a[1,i+2]*b[1,j+2];
           end for;
       end for;
       return result;
    end function;

    function negate(a)
       minv:=-a[1,2];
       maxv:=-a[1,1];
       n:=Integers()!(maxv+1-minv);
       result:=ZeroMatrix(Rationals(),1,2+n);
       result[1,1]:=minv;
       result[1,2]:=maxv;
       for i in [1..n] do
           result[1,i+2]:=a[1,n+3-i];
       end for;
       return result;
    end function;

    getdist:=function(dicelist)
       dist:=setupdie(dicelist[1]);
       for i in [2..#dicelist] do
         dist:=convolve(dist,setupdie(dicelist[i]));
       end for;
       return dist;
    end function;
    p1d:=getdist(p1dice);
    p2d:=getdist(p2dice);
    p1d:=negate(p1d);
    dfr:=convolve(p1d,p2d);
    lb:=Integers()!(2-dfr[1,1]);
    ub:=Integers()!(dfr[1,2]+1-dfr[1,1]);
    tot:=0;
    for i in [lb..ub] do
       tot:=tot+dfr[1,i+2];
    end for;

    print "probability player 2 wins =", tot, ", = approximately", RealField(10)!tot;
    print "probability of tie =", dfr[1,lb+1], "= approximately", RealField(10)!dfr[1,lb+1];
    print "probability player 1 wins =", 1-tot-dfr[1,lb+1], "= approximately", RealField(10)!(1-tot-dfr[1,lb+1]);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - I think I just missed the convolution step somehow. This also allowed me to make a program to generalize the predicted win percentage for any set of standard dice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The math is do-able, but messy.  You can set up a closed form for the computations, and then write a computer program do the heavy lifting.  So, you don't need to do a *simulation* as such.

I am assuming that die $dn$ refers to an $n$-sided die, whose (equally likely) sides are $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}.$

This means that the sum of the $[d6,d6,d6,d6]$ dice will be in the range of $\{4,5,6,\cdots,24\}.$

Similarly, the sum of the $[d20,d4]$ dice will be in the range of $\{2,3,\cdots,24\}.$

---

For $~n \in \{4,5,6, \cdots, 24\}, ~$ let $f(n)$ denote the probability that $[d6,d6,d6,d6]$ sum to $n$.

This can be routinely calculated by a computer program.  Simply have each of the dice loop through the values of $1$ through $6$, so that your program is examining $1296$ cases.  If, in the $1296$ cases, the sum $n$ occurs $r$ times, then $~\displaystyle f(n) = \frac{r}{1296}.$

For $~n \in \{2,3,4,5,6, \cdots, 24\}, ~$ let $g(n)$ denote the probability that $[d20,d4]$ sum to $n$.

This can also be routinely calculated by a computer program.  Simply have one die loop through the values $1$ through $20$, while the other die loops through the values $1$ through $4$, so that your program is examining $80$ cases.  If, in the $80$ cases, the sum $n$ occurs $r$ times, then $~\displaystyle g(n) = \frac{r}{80}.$

For $~n \in \{2,3,4,5,6, \cdots, 24\}, ~$ let $h(n)$ denote the probability that $[d20,d4]$ sum to strictly less than $n$.

For $~n \in \{2,3,4,5,6, \cdots, 24\}, ~$ let $j(n)$ denote the probability that $[d20,d4]$ sum to strictly greater than $n$.

This means that

- $h(2) = 0.$
- $h(n) = \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} g(k) ~: 3 \leq n \leq 24.$
- $j(24) = 0.$
- $j(n) = \sum_{k=n+1}^{24} g(k) ~: 2 \leq n \leq 23.$

Then, the chance of Player 2 winning is

$$\sum_{i=4}^{24} f(i) \times h(i).$$

Then, the chance of Player 1 winning is

$$\sum_{i=4}^{24} f(i) \times j(i).$$

Then, the chance of a tie is

$$\sum_{i=4}^{24} f(i) \times g(i).$$

Comment: A loop isn't really necessary for the d20+d4 case. $g(n) = \frac{1}{80} \min(4, n-1, 25-n)$. For the 4d6 case the loops might be simplest, or we can maybe determine the coefficients of the generating polynomial $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^4$.

Comment: @aschepler Or alternatively, both $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ can be computed by Stars and Bars.  For example, for $f(n)$ it is the number of solutions to $$x_1 + \cdots + x_4 = n ~: x_i \in \Bbb{Z}, ~1 \leq x_i \leq 6.$$  However, for this particular OP (i.e. original poster), given the posting, I regard the alternative approaches in either your comment or Stars and Bars as inferior to the looping process.  I judge it best to present a computation algorithm that is as absolutely simple and generic as possible, that still allows the OP to stretch their intuition around what is happening.